# Perform a search on range of dates and text fields and return a match for the first column

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have been trying a few solutions but I am pretty stuck. I am trying to find out if a date is included in a named range and return the period name of the corresponding row ( ie value in first column) 
I have tried, using match, vlookup, hlookup- but none of them seem to match the value.  I have even made sure that both are formatted as date.

Any help would be welcome!

[image: vlookup not matching]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3sdrkciyXkOgD23S-5rFvvDbK-bHFlh7yv4LwkpHiQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Aren't you looking for something more like `=index(f:f, match(b$2, g:g, 0))` ?

Comment: Thanks - but match only seems to work on a single row / column - so don't think it works for larger data sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(,1,IF(A3=G$7:AY$19,F$7:F$19,)))
```

- IF to get Column1
- TEXTJOIN to remove blanks

Comment: That is pretty awesome - can you explain how it works? Its not clear?

Comment: When I used the if statement alone, it returns an error that says `An array value could not be found` why does adding a 1 to the front resolve that?

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense now!